# Pandas Data Frame saving into csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I wonder how to save a new pandas Series into a csv file in a different column. Suppose I have two csv files which both contains a column as a 'A'. I have done some mathematical function on them and then create a new variable as a 'B'.

For example:

```
data = pd.read_csv('filepath')

data['B'] = data['A']*10

# and add the value of data.B into a list as a B_list.append(data.B)
```

This will continue until all of the rows of the first and second csv file has been reading.

I would like to save a column B in a new spread sheet from both csv files.
For example I need this result:

```
colum1(from csv1)        colum2(from csv2)     
     data.B.value             data.b.value
```

By using this code:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(B_list)).T.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

I won't get my preferred result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since each column in a pandas `DataFrame` is a pandas `Series`. Your *B_list* is actually a list of pandas `Series` which you can cast to `DataFrame()` constructor, then transpose (or as @jezrael shows a horizontal merge with `pd.concat(..., axis=1)`)

```
finaldf = pd.DataFrame(B_list).T
finaldf.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

And should csv have different rows, unequal series are filled with NANs at corresponding rows.

Comment: I am new to python and pandas :) . Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) column from `data1` with column from `data2` first:

```
df = pd.concat(B_list, axis=1)
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ,but I do not have data1 and data2 , data will be update in my loop till all the csv files are read.

Comment: `data1` is name of `Dataframe` 1 and `data2` second Dataframe.

Comment: I do not have 2 data frames as well. The original csv file will be updated by a new colum B and in the loop this column will be updated every time. I want to save this column in a new csv file before loosing the data.B.maybe I do not explain well what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand it well. Now it should working perfectly.